# Add computer name to Table

Tags: powershell

I'm using a script to fetch Windows OS version info from a list of remote machines. I want to add the computer hostnames to the output.

I was able to create the "ComputerName" header in the table output, but there is no actual computer name or hostname property in the registry hive that i'm looking at. I've tinkered around with it for a while trying to figure it out, but am not getting anywhere.

```
  Write-Host "Please select the machine list"


    Function Get-FileName($InitialDirectory) {

        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

        $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
        #$OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv|TXT (*.txt)| *.txt"
        $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
        $OpenFileDialog.filename

        }

    $inputfile = Get-FileName "C:"
    $Computer = get-content $inputfile



Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer {

    Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"

    } | Format-Table -Property ComputerName, ProductName, ReleaseId
```

This is what I am getting

```
ComputerName ProductName           ReleaseId
------------ -----------           ---------
             Windows 10 Enterprise 1709
```

Anyone know how I can populate the Computername column with the machines in my computerlist?

Comment: the usual way is to NOT use the problematic `Format-*` cmdlets and use either `Select-Object` or - better - build a custom object. [*grin*] simply have your scriptblock build a custom object & return that. if you want a demo of the idea, i can post one as an answer.

Comment: `Invoke-Command` automatically adds a `PSComputerName` property when run like this. Use `PSComputerName` instead of `ComputerName`.

Comment: Lee_Dailey and TheMadTechnician. Both of these helped. I'm now getting the output I wanted. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-Command` automatically adds a `PSComputerName` property when run like this. Use `PSComputerName` instead of `ComputerName`.

```
Write-Host "Please select the machine list"


Function Get-FileName($InitialDirectory) {

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    #$OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv|TXT (*.txt)| *.txt"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename

    }

$inputfile = Get-FileName "C:"
$Computer = get-content $inputfile

$Results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer {

    Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"

}
$Results | Format-Table -Property PSComputerName, ProductName, ReleaseId
```

I also recommend capturing the results, and then piping that to `Format-Table`, so that the results can be used again to output to file or something, or filter, or sort.